# NSManagedContext issue fetching from context multiple times

Tags: objective-c, core-data, nsmanagedobjectcontext

I have two view controllers. One a searchResults tableview controller (VC1) where the user see a list of rows matching a selection criteria and other ViewDetail (tableview controller) (VC2) where the user sees Detail for the chosen row of VC1. The info required to fetch detail for the chosen row  along with the managedContext reference are passed from VC1 to VC2 in the prepareforsegue method of VC1 by setting the relevant properties of VC2. During my test, I switched between (using the navigation controller back button) VC1 and VC2 each time selecting a different row on VC1 to see the detail of a different item. This works normally for 7-15 times of switching but crashes suddenly after some attempts of switching. I have investigated this as far as I could but stuck without a solution and hence posting this. Please help.   The error is that a particular Array is out of bounds for index 0. While I understand however, I do not expect this array which is populated by results of a fetch request to be empty. Hence I suspect that there is something wrong with the managedcontext.  Snippet of code from VC2 is provided

```
//All this is in  ViewDidLoad of VC2 App crashes at the last line of this snippet. trying to get an object at index 0 which is non existent but should not be ...
NSFetchRequest *request  = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@" cameraid ==  %@",(NSNumber *)self.selectedCameraid];
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Cameras"
                                          inManagedObjectContext:self.managedContext];

//Configure core data request
[request setEntity:entity];
[request setPredicate:predicate];

//Execute request
NSError *error = nil;

NSMutableArray *mutableFetchResults =  [[self.managedContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error] mutableCopy];

if (mutableFetchResults == nil) {
    // Handle the error.
    NSLog(@"Some error in fetching results");

}
NSLog(@"Mutable fetch results data %@",mutableFetchResults);
self.resultsArray = mutableFetchResults;
Cameras *rowdata = [self.resultsArray objectAtIndex:0]; //Cameras is a managed object
```

Comment: _" I do not expect this array which is populated by results of a fetch request to be empty."_  You are logging `mutableFetchResults` just before the line that throws the exception; so is the array empty before the crash?

Comment: Yes mutableFetchResults is empty at the time of crash. It must have one record, which it does until it crashes.

Comment: and are `self.managedContext` and `self.selectedCameraid` both non-nil when the crash occurs?

Comment: Yes, self.managedContext and selectedCameraid are both non-nil.

Comment: Then I don't see anything wrong with the code you've posted.  This issue must lie elsewhere.  If it always throws an exception with the same camera ID - then that ID is not in the persistent store.  If it crashes inconsistently on a given camera ID, then memory management is suspect, assuming you're working solely on the main queue.

Comment: Hmmm.. it does crash on random cameraid. I suspect it to do with memory management as well, but cant figure out where. The code uses ARC and I had set an exception breakpoint and it shows that the context has a number of change object although the coredata store is used for reading persistent data. Also i used [self.managedContext reset], this seems to resolve the problem (atleast it didnt  crash in the 25-30 switches between VC1 and VC2), however this has side effects in that the previous screen VC1 looses data when the context is reset. Is there anyway to investigate potential memory issue?

Answer (score 0):

After a bit of further digging I found the issue... I am type casting a string as NSNumber (NSNumber *)self.selectedCameraid  in the above code. Apparently this is what has been causing the crash. I converted the NSString object to a NSNumber object using NSNumberformatter and everything seems to work fine.  I realised it is not safe to type cast objects in this manner.